# Java mouse listener- comparing two movements.

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

I have an idea, however I'm not sure how exactly to implement it.

I want to use the mouselistener in java to track the movement of the mouse in an application. eg. a game, therefor tracking the crosshair. And compare that to the raw input of a mouse.
I can track the movement of the mouse in a JFrame, that's fine. However I want to track the movement in a program, as mentioned above, a game.

The end result, should track both the movement in the JFrame and the game and send a flag if the movements don't correlate.

Could someone please put me on the right track of setting up the mouselistener to listen on a program?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MouseListener can only track in a GUI component.

It sounds like you basically want to try to implement a kind of cheat protection and I don't think Java can do that. All of the listeners are only inside their components. You could maybe track movement through JNI but I doubt it would be any different than what the listener gives you. Here is an existing JNI library that does it if you want an adventure: https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/

If you are gung-ho about this you might look in to the Robot class which you could test with. Robot can send mouse movements and you can see if the listeners do or don't pick it up. Robot is the Java class you can use to make cheat-type bots (though it is not for that).

Comment: I'll check out the JNI library. Thanks for the response, I really hope it is possible in java!

Comment: You're welcome. It appears you don't really have to know JNI to try using JNativeHook.

Comment: It looks quite good, it caters for acceleration, sensitivity. Perhaps if I could compare the global mouse movements with the JNativeHook and compare that against the crosshair movement. Which will be another challenge, grabbing the crosshair movement, that is.